# ASM for avr mega8 does not work with mullpte outputs

Tags: assembly, avr

I have some ASM code here I use to get data and put it in to 3 variables. 1 works the other 2 are always the same.

unsigned char C,P,D;

```
    asm volatile(
```

.
.
.

```
        //   0          1           2
    : "=&r" (C) ,"=&w" (P), "=&a" (D)
        //      3                           4
    : "I" (_SFR_IO_ADDR(PINB)) , "I" (_SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTD)));


    command = C;
    requestedPort = P;
    requestedDevice = D;
```

I could post the entire ASM but I'm pretty sure its how I set up the inline asm. To fill in data I use a simple port like so.

```
    "clr %0 "       "\n\t"  //zero out my data.
    "sbis %3, 6"    "\n\t"  //test pin
    "rjmp bit1"     "\n\t"  if clear
    "sbr  %0, 0x80" "\n\t"  if set
    "bit1:"         "\n\t"
```

I do this for each out 0,1, and 2. but 0 is the only one that works. There other two never change but clearly should be watching my scope. Did I do the asm inputs/outputs right? Is the ASM clobbering my data?